# GFCI Light Is On, Test Button Doesn't Work

Tags: electrical, gfci

I am replacing an ungrounded outlet with a 15 amp GFCI. After removing the old receptacle, I noticed there were two wires coming off each screw on the load side.

I 3-way pig-tailed each side with a new wire (hot and neutral), and connected the new single wires to the load side of the GFCI. I connected the remaining two wires to line. On turning the breaker back on, the GFCI indicator light is solid green, but the test button cannot be pressed. The downstream load has no power.

Is this the right way to fix the double load, and how should I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Non-GFCI receptacles don’t have “line” and “load” terminals. They’re all equivalent. And for what it’s worth, if you pigtail all the wires that were in the box, the downstream devices will not be protected (may or may not be what you want).

Comment: @nobody As of the OP's current edit, it seems the pigtailing was more complicated than just all the wires together.

Comment: Photos would be a big big help here. There seem to be multiple assumptions about what you actually did that photos would immediately clarify.

Answer (score 6):

According to your description, you connected nothing to the line terminals and everything to the load terminals.

Possibly you connected some random wire to the line terminals, and just wrote poorly. Since a non-GFCI receptacle does not have "Line" and "Load" terminals, you actually need to establish which incoming cable is the line when replacing one with a GFCI, and connect the correct wires (only) to the LINE terminals.

Comment: Ah, thank you. So if i (most likely) wired line to load and vice versa, i just need to figure out which is line then and rewire? Are there any potential safety issues with leaving this circuit breaker on until i fix it?

Comment: And, as @nobody correctly answered and then deleted, you may well need to press the reset button **first,** even when correctly wired. That varies with GFCI logic, but is common. And the "meaning" of "the light is on" also varies (check the documentation, even if you have to grab it from the trash can, for the meaning of that - but that can be misleading (not mean what it says it does) if you wired the line to the load.)

Answer (score 6):

On plain receptacles, there is no such thing as "Load".  They are all "Line".

The Load terminals on a GFCI should never be used, except for a specific feature that most people are not aiming to use.  Using that feature has requirements that you probably don't want to deal with, and complications that sometimes force complicated troubleshooting.

That feature allows you to extend GFCI protection to other outlets from here.  However the wiring must be correct, and you must label each of those outlets "GFCI Protected", *which means, you must know where they all are*.  If you didn't even know GFCIs *could do that*, then real simple: don't use Load.  Or if you knew but aren't trying to do that, again, don't use Load.

It's perfectly reasonable to say "this is not a useful feature for me" - not least, it solves the problem of an outlet going dead for no conceivable reason, only later to find out a GFCI behind a bookshelf had tripped.

Comment: This is all so true. I have seen thousands and thousands of dollars wasted on un-needed electrical service calls, just because folks don't understand how GFCI's work. They should teach this stuff in Jr High Schools to everyone.

Comment: @kreemoweet True, but this would be solved if people would install the "GFCI Protected" labeling which is required by NEC.  (NEC 110.3(b) -> instructions part 8(C).  How do I know it is 8(c) for every brand of GFCI? UL magic :)